# is there any way to hide a query string from showing in search and filter using asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search, query-string, querystringparameter

I implement a basic sorting - filtration with sorting

the index code in controller

```
 public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
        {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
            ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                page = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                searchString = currentFilter;
            }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var students = from s in db.Students
                           select s;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                students = students.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                       || s.FirstMidName.Contains(searchString));
            }
            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "name_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
                case "Date":
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                case "date_desc":
                    students = students.OrderByDescending(s => s.EnrollmentDate);
                    break;
                default:  // Name ascending 
                    students = students.OrderBy(s => s.LastName);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(students.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
        }
```

the code worked well 
[image]

[image]

what I'm asking about is there any way to implement the same code without showing the query parameter to end user as shown in images.

is it available to hide this parameter using something like view model - form collection or using route based - and is there any issues related to security with this way of work with query string or not 
- note that this example is a just a demo to what i want to do using contoso university (Microsoft demo) and for sure in this context i doesn't need to hide a query string but in another context ( using ado.net stored procedure ) can show some database architecture –

Comment: Have you thought of using a model binder with a string?

Comment: You can look into removing the extra part of the query string via jQuery after the page loads

Comment: if there any snippet or a code to follow this would be a good point to start from it , thanks

Comment: Why on earth do your want to 'hide' it? The user typed _"a"_ in the textbox so they would expect it to be in the query string

Comment: in another context ( using ado.net stored procedure ) can show some database architecture

Comment: @user4833581. What is your last comment supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Not every query string causes security breaches. You have to define what are the sensitive data which should not be shown on the query string.
2. If you want to hide that you need to use "POST" instead of "GET". However, with package sniffing tools like Fiddler or browsers' debugging tools, the query parameters are still discoverable.
3. Beware of SQL injection if you simply construct SQL statement in the code. For example, someone might pass "; drop table xx;" as a query string.
4. Query string can be encrypted - https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-QueryString-Parameter-Values-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Got downvote for no reason. However, I hope my effort is helpful for someone.

Comment: I appreciated your effort, I didn't downvote your answer.as it helps me so I upvoted it to equal the downvote

Comment: The query string is the value the user typed in the textbox - there is nothing 'sensitive' about it. OP cannot use a POST. There is no 'SQL injection' involved here (its using EF). And encrypting it makes no sense (and would not be possible anyway). Nothing you have stated here has anything to do with OP's question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke He updated the question based on the answer here and please feel free to share what I don't know ;)

Comment: OP cannot 'hide' the query string - if it was then the value would not be sent to the server and the controller method would not work. Why OP thinks they would want to do that makes no sense.

Comment: And OP's edit states _but in another context_ but has not stated what that is or why they think they need to _hide the query string_